# libheif giving unknown file type error debian 10

Tags: debian, conversion, imagemagick, jpeg

I tried using `heif-convert 100 3313.heif 3.jpg` to convert my file from .heic to .jpg, but it keeps giving me the error message `Unknown file type in 3313.heif`. What does this mean? I have libde265 and ImageMagick also installed.

Comment: Could you please post the output of `file 3313.heif`?

Answer (score 0):

On my box (Mint 19) the syntax is:

```
$ heif-convert 
USAGE: heif-convert [-q quality] <filename> <output>
```

So I think you miss the `-q` flag. Try:

```
heif-convert -q 100 3313.heif 3.jpg
```